# Trouble with createLinearGradient in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a trouble with linear gradient in canvas.

I'm trying to create and animate a dynamic canvas element after clicking somewhere in the screen and it's working on the desktop but it doesn't seem to work on Mobile (chrome) if I use `ctx.createLinearGradient` to fill the circle that was created.

```js
var circle = new Circle(circleProp);//circleProp is all propertys for new circle

function onMenuClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var posX = e.pageX || e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  var posY = e.pageY || e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

  if(menuToggle){

    circle.paint(usrAllCont);// here is ewerything to make it work;

    usrMenu.style.display = "block";
    usrMenu.style.zIndex = "100";
    usrMenu.opacity();

    menuToggle = false;
  }else{

    usrMenu.opacity();
    menuToggle = true;

    circle.paint(usrAllCont);// here is ewerything to make it work back;
  }
}
```

Thanks you!

**[Include questioner's test code from their comment]**

```js
var Circle = function(prop){
  this.width = prop.width;
  this.height = prop.height;
  this.r = prop.r;
  this.halfR = this.r / 2;
  this.step = this.r / 30;
  this.currentStep = this.r / 30;
  this.inProcesStep;
  this.x = prop.defX;
  this.y = prop.defY;

  this.anim = true;
  this.toggleAnim = false;
  this.resize = false;
  this.direction = "front";

  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.canvas.width = this.width;
  this.canvas.height = this.height;
  this.canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  this.canvas.style.top = "0px";

  //this.color = "rgb(25,245,170)"

  this.gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0, 0, prop.height);
  this.gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgb(100,150,250");
  this.gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgb(0,250,250");

};
Circle.prototype.paint = function(parent){
  this.parent = parent;
  this.parent.appendChild(this.canvas);

  var ctx = this.ctx;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.gradient;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.halfR ,0 ,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

};


var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var h = window.screen.height;
var radius = function(width, height){
  var sum = Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2);
  return Math.sqrt(sum);
};
var conteiner = document.getElementById("conteiner");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", onBtnClick);
btn.addEventListener("touchend", onBtnClick);

var circleProp = {
  width: w,
  height: h,
  r: radius(w, h),
  defX: 25,
  defY: 25
};
var circle = new Circle(circleProp);

function onBtnClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var posX = e.pageX || e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  var posY = e.pageY || e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

  circle.paint(conteiner);
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">click me</div>
<div id="conteiner"></div>
```

Comment: Post your code in the question

Comment: var circle = new Circle(circleProp);//circleProp is properties for new canvas;

Comment: //After click on button;
function onMenuClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var posX = e.pageX || e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        var posY = e.pageY || e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

        if(menuToggle){

            circle.paint(usrAllCont);

            menuToggle = false;
        }else{

            usrMenu.opacity();
            menuToggle = true;

            circle.paint(usrAllCont);//here is everething what should make it's work
        }
    }

Comment: hum since you've got "ewerything to make it work" on your side and we don't have anything to chew on, I'd say you're the only one able to find out what is going on.

Comment: I make a little preview
http://test.supersyte.in.ua/test.html
There I use ctx.createLinearGradient.. and it's doesn't work. If I change gradient on fillStyle = "some color" it's works great

Comment: **You have a typo:** You need closing parens on both of your `addColorStop` statements.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAA!!!
How could I miss it!!))